# transfer Encrypted File by python : InvalidToken error

Tags: python, cryptography, python-3.7

I want to send a file with a simple socket program in python.

Receiver :

```py
    import socket
    import sys
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(("0.0.0.0",9999))
    s.listen(10) 

    i = 1
    while True:
        sc, address = s.accept()

        print(address)
        f = open('file_'+ str(i),'wb')
        i=i+1
        fi = Fernet(b'RkmYkE0W0oirK7e-aq7cfRGaq0nnn_GSvLIbLZHfpfw=sssdsdds')
        while (True):

            l = fi.decrypt(sc.recv(1024))
            f.write(l)

            if not l:
                break

        f.close()
        sc.close()
        print('copied the file.')
```

sender:

```py
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    message = "my deep dark secret".encode()

    #key = Fernet.generate_key()
    fi = Fernet(b'RkmYkE0W0oirK7e-aq7cfRGaq0nnn_GSvLIbLZHfpfw=sssdsdds')
    encrypted = fi.encrypt(message)
    #print(key)
    print(encrypted)
    decrypted = fi.decrypt(encrypted)
    print(decrypted.decode("utf-8"))
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(("192.168.1.141", 9999))
    f = open("l.pdf", "rb")
    l = fi.encrypt(f.read(1024))
    while (l):

        s.send(l)

        l = f.read(1024)
    s.close()
```

but I have faced this error:

```
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken 
raise Invalid Signature("Signature did not match digest.")
```

What should I do to decrypt my file? I have tested this transfer by a PDF file.

Comment: use base64 encoding before sending, and decode it on the receiver side.

Comment: Inside of your while loop you are doing `l = f.read(1024)` but that data is straight from the file - It has not been encrypted.

Comment: So what should i write instead of l=f.read(1024) ??